# Problem in understanding a particular dynamic programming pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14, dynamic-programming

I am new to dynamic programming. I am unable to figure out one of the generalised pattern (according to the writer) on the site https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/458695/dynamic-programming-patterns .

The portion in which I am having a problem is -

**Decision Making**
The general problem statement for this pattern is forgiven situation decide whether to use or not to use the current state. So, the problem requires you to make a decision at a current state.

**Statement**
Given a set of values find an answer with an option to choose or ignore the current value.

**Approach**
If you decide to choose the current value use the previous result where the value was ignored; vice-versa, if you decide to ignore the current value use previous result where value was used.

```
 // i - indexing a set of values
 // j - options to ignore j values
 for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= k; ++j) {
       dp[i][j] = max({dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j] + arr[i], dp[i-1][j-1]});
       dp[i][j-1] = max({dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j-1] + arr[i], arr[i]});
     }
   }
```

Please help me to understand what it means and how it works. It will be a great help.
(I commented on the post but got no reply).

Comment: These equations depend on the problem you  are trying to solve, they are not fixed.

Comment: @SomeDude " // j - options to ignore j values " what does this line mean. For a particular, we will have only two option to either choose it or ignore it.